# C - Erro ao ler um caractere usando scanf(): comando scanf() é "pulado"

Tags: c, string, char, input-output

Gostaria de saber o porque do meu código não aceitar a leitura de caracteres, simplesmente pula essa etapa e realiza a próxima.

```
float altura, pesoIdeal = 0;
char sexo;

printf("Informe a sua altura : ");
scanf("%f",&altura);

printf("Informe o seu sexo : ");
scanf("%c",&sexo);


if(sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M'){
    pesoIdeal = (72.7 * altura) - 58;
} else{
    pesoIdeal = (62.1 * altura) - 44.7;
}

printf("O seu peso ideal eh %.2f kg \n",pesoIdeal);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Provavelmente é lixo no buffer de entrada. Substitua: `scanf("%c",&sexo);` por: `scanf(" %c",&sexo);`, note o espaço antes do `%c`.

Comment: Veja mais detalhes no item 12.26 de http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/.

Comment: Resolveu o problema, muito obrigado!

Comment: Não possuo conhecimento técnico para explicar com precisão o que ocorreu, mas pelas minhas poucas experiências com C, arrisco em dizer que talvez seja um erro no buffer. Tente usar o comando "fflush(stdin);" antes do scanf, para "limpar" o buffer. Um abraço e boa sorte! PS: Já lidei com SOs que possuíam alguns problemas com entradas de dados de caracteres pelo comando scanf. Se esse for o seu caso, tente usar a função "getchar()"; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/.

Answer (score 1):

Esses problemas são comuns no uso do `scanf()`, [e ocorrem também quando usa-se outros comandos de captura de entrada em conjunto com o mesmo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-with-scanf-when-there-is-fgetsgetsscanf-after-it/).

Para ficar mais claro, analisemos o seu código. A primeira vez que você faz uso do `scanf()` ocorre na seguinte linha:

```
scanf("%f",&altura);
```

Precisamente, neste trecho um número `float` é lido a partir da entrada padrão `stdin` e armazenado no endereço de memória apontado pela variável `altura`. Nessa leitura, o `scanf` ignora o caracter `\n`que incluímos no `stdin` no momento em que apertamos `ENTER`no teclado para confirmar a inserção do nosso número.

Dessa forma, o caracter de quebra de linha continua no buffer de entrada.

A seguir, o próximo uso do comando ocorre em:

```
scanf("%c",&sexo);
```

Nesse momento, o buffer de entrada `stdin`ainda contém `\n`. O comando lê esse caracter imediatamente e naturalmente parece "pular" para a linha seguinte ao invés de aguardar que o usuário digite algum caracter e confirme sua entrada.

O que acontece então é que o `scanf()`lê um caracter indesejado, que é o `\n`, numa segunda execução do comando.

Para limpar o buffer de entrada, você pode intercalar as chamadas de `scanf()` com um comando [`getc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc). Seu programa ficaria desta forma:

```
float altura, pesoIdeal = 0;
char sexo;

printf("Informe a sua altura : ");
scanf("%f",&altura);
getc(stdin); //getc(stdin) irá consumir o caracter `\n` do buffer de
             // entrada impedindo que interfira na captura de 
             //input posterior

printf("Informe o seu sexo : ");
scanf("%c",&sexo);


if(sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M'){
    pesoIdeal = (72.7 * altura) - 58;
} else{
    pesoIdeal = (62.1 * altura) - 44.7;
}

printf("O seu peso ideal eh %.2f kg \n",pesoIdeal);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Note que não atribuímos o resultado de `getc()`a variável alguma pois estamos interessados em descartar este valor.

Uma solução mais robusta, envolvendo expressões regulares e mais compacta pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045/scanf-n-skips-the-2nd-input-but-n-does-not-why).

Abraços!